# Is it possible to animate moving and fading in text with CSS3?

Tags: css, css-transitions

What I'm trying to do is slide the first bit of text to the right and then fade in the hidden text.. possible?

Still testing a couple things with CSS3 and was wondering if this was possible: http://jsfiddle.net/ht65k/

**HTML**

```
<ul id="socialnetworks">
    <li>
        <span><a  href="#">Fade in Text</a></span>
        <a href="#">Slide to Right</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#socialnetworks li{
    /*border-bottom: 1px #ddd solid;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;*/
    -moz-transition-property: all;
    -webkit-transition-property: all;
    -o-transition-property: all;
    transition-property: all;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    transition-duration: 0.8s;
    }

#socialnetworks li:hover{ padding-left: 120px; }
#socialnetworks span{ display: none; }
#socialnetworks span:hover{ display: visible;}
```

Comment: As a general principle, can you include a little of the relevant code bits inline in your message so casual readers can learn a little from your question without going to your fiddle?

Comment: As nice as this looks, [IE users won't get to see the transitions](http://caniuse.com/#search=transition). You may want to use some sort of Javascript solution if the animation is that important to you.

Answer (score 1):

You're close.

1. [`visible` is not a valid value for `display`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/display)
2. You need to move where the `:hover` pseudo-class is applied, since you cannot hover over a hidden element.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/r5Hcu. It's not animated, but you should be able to figure out the rest.

**Amended CSS**

```
#socialnetworks li {
    -moz-transition-property: all;
    -webkit-transition-property: all;
    -o-transition-property: all;
    transition-property: all;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    transition-duration: 0.8s;
}

#socialnetworks li:hover {
    padding-left: 120px;
}

#socialnetworks span {
    display: none;
}

#socialnetworks:hover span {
    display: inline;
}
```

---

Re: animating the `display` property — [Transitions on the display: property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/css-3-transitions-on-the-display-property).